# Will a Pokémon retain in-battle type changes when Mega Evolving?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Some moves change or add element typings to a Pokemon, such as Soak (changes the Pokémon to pure Water-type), Forest's Curse (Adds Grass-type) and Trick-or-Treat (Adds Ghost Type).

If a Pokemon Mega Evolves after being affected by these moves, will it retain the changes made to it's type?

What about Pokemon like Charizard (X-Mega) or Pinsir, that change type when Mega Evolving? Are they affected differently?

Comment: I remember how my Charizard has been soaked (pure-water), then Mega evolved it (X, Fire/Dragon) and after that an enemy ice-typed attack has been normal effective against Charizard. Seems like mega evolving overwrites types. I dont know its handled when Mega doesnt touch types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Mega Pokemon will have the typing that it should be having just like in a situation where it was not hit with such moves.

If for example Charizard is hit with Soak, then mega evolves into Charizard X, Charizard X will have the typing Fire/Dragon.

Similarly, a Lucario hit with Forest's Curse will have the Fighting/Steel typing after mega evolving.

You can see a test video if you download the following video picturing how Pinsir didn't have its ghost typing after being hit with Trick-or-Treat then mega evolving (hopefully, the video will remain online for a while):

```
2HCW-WWWW-WWW4-EXEJ
```

(Shadow Sneak from Pumpkaboo has normal damage on Mega Pinsir instead of Super Effective)

And this one is with Lucario:

```
JBZG-WWWW-WWW4-EXFW
```

(Shadow Ball from Pumpkaboo has normal damage on Mega Lucario instead of Super Effective)

<sub>Sorry if the Pokemon and trainer names are in Japanese!</sub>